# Dialog Box Using VB Script

Tags: vbscript

Hello I have some knowledge about VB Script, but i need some help so that it will help me to move further and study in VB Script.

I want to make dialog box which will contain :

1. Two radio button
2. one Text field to enter some value
3. OK and CANCEL button

so, could you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support custom dialogs. You can either use the [Internet Explorer COM object](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php#InternetExplorer) to emulate a dialog, or create an [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Either way you're building a web page with a form.