# Msgbox changing button caption for vbs

Tags: button, vbscript, caption, msgbox

```
Option Explicit
Const conForReading = 1
Dim objFSO, objReadFile, objFile, contents, result, shell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\read.txt") 

If objFile.Size  Then 
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\read.txt", 1, False)
contents = objReadFile.ReadAll
result = MsgBox ("text2" & contents & "text1",vbYesNo+vbExclamation,"TITLE")
Select Case result
Case vbYes
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
shell.Open "D:\folder"
Case vbNo
End Select
objReadFile.close

Else 
End If  

Set objFSO = Nothing 
Set objReadFile = Nothing 
WScript.Quit()
```

I have this vbs file, and I want to change vbYesNo captions, for yes Open Folder and for no Exit. But I don't know how to do it, and I couldn't find a way to do this. Maybe I am missing an easy thing because I am new to programming. but I would like to learn that.

Comment: I would recommend using a title for your message box that says "Open Folder?" so that it's clear just from reading the title what the "Yes" button will do. Also, in the message box text, describe what clicking the buttons will do: *Click "Yes" to open the folder. Click "No" to exit.*

Comment: That's what I do right now but having those buttons changed would be nice, is it impossible?

Comment: Not with pure VBScript, no. You could create your own message box as an ActiveX control using another language (like VB6) and call it from VBScript. Other than that, your options are pretty limited.

Comment: You can also create custom dialogs via the Internet Explorer COM object or HTA. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15770942/1630171).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. There is no option for that with the MessageBox function. Your options are:

```
OK
OK, Cancel
Abort, Retry, Ignore
Yes, No, Cancel
Yes, No
Retry, Cancel
```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(v=vs.84).aspx